# Facebooki API page management, mark message as read?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making an app which would allow the user to manage his page's messages. I ran into an issue where I cannot mark messages as read, or in other words "handle" them properly.

Using Facebook's Graph API, i can make calls to:

***{conversation-id}/messages***

which allows me to read and write messages, however it does not allow me to "mark a message as read" or in other words, if a user was to access his page and go to Inbox, he'd see the messages and could mark them as "read", "followup", "spam" and "done".

The important ones being "read" and "done".
The marking as read also automatically happens as soon as a message is opened, which makes this behavior very necessary since `unseen_count` parameter gets the value of 0. However when we access the message through the API, we do not "read it" and the `unseen_count` remains whatever it was.

This makes it pretty hard to make "notifications" for the user when he has new messages in conversations.

I know that we cannot do anything with each individual message and need to do our requests on a conversation thread, but is there a way to mark a conversation as read?